# Uploaded image overriding mask image

Tags: adobe-illustrator

We are allowing user to upload image on Mask image as below [ Svg & Png ]

**Mask image** :

[image]

user upload another image on mask image [phone case] :

[image]

Once user drag the uploaded image to top, half of the 2nd square is overrided by the uploaded image. but another half is not overrided. but  uploaded image should not override the original image.

[image]

Our Graphic designer using Illustrator.

**Update** : Below is another example

Initial :

[image]

Later : Once user drag uploaded image to top : Its displaying black straight line , that should not display.... how to correct these kind of mistakes ?

[image]

here is [link](http://dailyorders.com/productdesigner/index/full/id/11788/#parentVerticalTab2) to check : once you click on "Browse" button & upload the image, than click on the uploaded image, than it will display on mask image, than drag the image to top.....

Edit 2 : Our Designer followed as below image to create SVG....

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to implement this in Illustrator, or are you asking how to code for this in some kind of app?

Comment: @BillyKerr i want to create mask image so that once user upload the image on mask image, than that should not override the original image. I want to implement this in illustrator.....

Comment: What does this have to do with Illustrator?

Comment: I don't understand. Is your finished product a phone cover produced by dailyorders.com? Or are you making dailyorders.com? I get the same problem with the line. The mask svg looks ok (but I don't know) so it could be a problem with the method you use to draw the svg to canvas?

Comment: @Scott seems like our designer is doing something wrong with the illustrator , he followed steps as  here  : https://prnt.sc/gv3lkw  , did he missed something? once he gave the mask image, than we will place the mask image [here](http://dailyorders.com/productdesigner/index/full/id/11788/#parentVerticalTab2) & upload new image on that....

Comment: @Wolff  our designer  followed steps as  here  : https://prnt.sc/gv3lkw  , did he missed something? once he gave the mask image, than we will place the mask image in site [here](http://dailyorders.com/productdesigner/index/full/id/11788/#parentVerticalTab2) & upload new image on that.... than we face the issues as images in question....

Comment: Sorry, but you are repeating yourself. I still don't understand what kind of product you are making.

Comment: @Wolff we are selling personalized phone case, means what image user will upload on phone case, than we will print that image on phone case [ example : iphone 6 ] & deliver to product. so when user upload the custom image on phone case , its giving some issues as images i posted in question, means user image overriding the `camera & flash hole of mask image`  you can check by uploading in [link](http://dailyorders.com/productdesigner/index/full/id/11788/#parentVerticalTab2)

Comment: Ok. Isn't this a coding problem? And not an Illustrator problem? How are you drawing svg on the website?

Comment: @Wolff yes, its not coding issue, because some images are working fine, but some svg images giving issues as images posted in qustion, our designer followed as here : https://prnt.sc/gv3lkw , than we are uploading those svg in [link](http://dailyorders.com/productdesigner/index/full/id/11788/#parentVerticalTab2) & than allowing user to upload his custom image on our svg image.....

Comment: It's a pretty cheap move to throw a bounty on a question that is unclear and is being voted to close it. From what I can see.. the mask **does not match** the image. You can [clearly see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X78u7.jpg) that the mask has **completely** different shapes than the underlying phone preview. This is a coding/web site issue, not a graphic design issue.

Comment: @Scott Thanks for your comment & review. but for some svg images [mask] , its working fine.... but not for others..... once our graphic designer do lot of changes , finally it will come to one shape. but he is not getting what actuall he need to do to correct it. he is trying `trail & error` method now..... also please check [link](http://dailyorders.com/productdesigner/index/full/id/11787/#parentVerticalTab2) , `mask match the image`but  still we have issue......

Comment: Okay so in one instance the mask *does* match the preview shape.. but clearly in the other links you've posted the mask is incorrect and does *not* match the preview shape. Whether that's an issue with the designer outputting the wrong mask, or the web site calling the wrong mask image is indeterminable by anyone not directly involved in the files/site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is highly unlikely to be of benefit to anyone who doesn't have access to the files in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create your phone template, and make sure it is a combined shape including the inside rectangles. Use the Path Finder *Minus Front* button to punch the holes in the case.
2. Select the template shape, and copy and paste in front.
3. Paste your graphic or photo and position it.
4. Click *Object > Arrange > Send Backward*
5. With the graphic/photo still selected, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+click (or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+click on Mac) on the phone case. This will select both the graphic and the phone case.
6. Click *Object > Clipping Mask > Make*.

Now the graphic is inside the clipping mask.

You can double click on the graphic to enter the clipping mask group, and move the graphic to any position you want.  The clipping mask will clip the graphic wherever you move it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Our Designer followed as : https://prnt.sc/gv3lkw & mentioned this : `1)Took new document size pixel 1200x1200 and upload images of phone case mask in background to trace & lock layer.

2)Take a new layer and take rounded rectangle tool, Trace how phone case looks after doing phone case shape and camera shape and flash Shape now take 1200 x1200 

rectangle and select all shapes phone shape,camera shape, flash shape and 1200x1200 rectangle and In pathfinder > divide. now hide phone case shape . I shown in screenshot please check screenshot   :  i saved as png and svg....`

Comment: Please tell your designer to use this question for further inquiries, and not start [new ones which are really puzzling to read](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/99619/we-are-allowing-to-upload-png-and-svg-image-i-attracted-the-link-and-use-illustr) :)

Comment: @profile1 Is that a question?

Comment: @BillyKerr  yes, sorry to say that your solution didt helped our designer.  he said issue is different.  we are facing issues as in the question & our designer created png & svg images by following https://prnt.sc/gv3lkw , but still we are facing the issue, we want to know what changes we need to do to get solution.....

Comment: @profile1 You asked me how to implement this in Illustrator, which is what I provided. I have no idea how your designer is implementing this on the web. Ask him to fix it. If he can't, then hire another one who can.

Comment: @BillyKerr have a look at the questions by the other account (the one I linked to, and the more recent one by the same user).

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher - oh, I see.  That explains a lot.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher Thanks for your comment, I told our designer to delete the question & we both are different.....

Comment: @BillyKerr you are telling about clipping mask of phone case in illustrator. but we don't want that.... we want the png and svg to make in illustrator and upload in website. it as png as background  and Svg as mask image. but once user upload the image in [website](http://dailyorders.com/productdesigner/index/full/id/11788/#parentVerticalTab2) , it has some issue in svg mask image & you can see those images in question....

Comment: @profile1 You need to isolate whether this is an issue with illustrator or svg/javascript implementation in various browsers before asking. You seem to believe it's an illustrator issue but this still isn't certain and could entirely change the scope of the question. In summary, it's really important to know what it the real problem is before looking for a solution. Not just to know that a problem exists.

Comment: @biscuitstack it's an issue with svg for sure, for some svg it works fine ?& for other svg it produce issues as images i posted in question.....

Comment: With respect, I don't think you're interpreting a lot of the advice here thoroughly. 'issue with... svg/javascript *implementation in various browsers*' was the full sentence and an important context for the advice given. Not just the word svg and agreeing it's an issue based on picking and choosing part of a sentence. I would advise reading the suggestions here again thoroughly and, if the specifics of the problem can't be deduced, passing the project onto somebody more familiar with the ins and outs of getting assets as far as production.